# Gettting error ""Uncaught TypeError: Object.assign is not a function" in react app on Chrome Browser 45 . How to transpile this in node modules?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, babeljs

I am getting this error in react app which i am using webview  so getting error on Chrom browser 45. I using CRA, and this object.assign is used in nodemodules. How to transpile and handle thi.

Comment: How are you polyfilling other stuff? Are you loading `@babel/polyfill` or using something more focused like `preset-env`'s `usage`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am using create react app and it's using babel

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing something like this in your webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include: [
      path.join(root, 'src')
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(<your broken node module>)\/).*/
  }
```